# Numerical optimization fails in for Loop

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

I am doing numerical optimization using Gekko in for loop. In the loop I am reading an element of array to optimize the objective function with constraint against that particular element. However, optimization stops after some iteration and gives following error: **Exception:  @error: Solution Not Found**. I then pass the same element to optimzation routine but without loop and for the same element it gives me a solution.

Comment: Can you post the code?  Otherwise, no one has anything to go on here.

Comment: Thanks jonsca. I used try and except command to resolve the issue. So for a particular input value when IPOPT fails to give the solution I asked it to try it again and then It gives me the solution. Sometime in second try and some time in the third try. Seems like it is related to Gekko.

Comment: The initial guesses are zero unless specifically defined. Sometimes a failed solution can be a good initial guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem to use Gekko in a loop. Here is an example with a single-threaded process.

[image: optimization]

**Gekko in Optimization Loop**

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

# Optimize at mesh points
x = np.arange(20.0, 30.0, 2.0)
y = np.arange(30.0, 50.0, 4.0)
amg, bmg = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Initialize results array
obj = np.empty_like(amg)

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
objective = float('NaN')

a,b = m.Array(m.FV,2)

# model variables, equations, objective
x1 = m.Var(1,lb=1,ub=5)
x2 = m.Var(5,lb=1,ub=5)
x3 = m.Var(5,lb=1,ub=5)
x4 = m.Var(1,lb=1,ub=5)
m.Equation(x1*x2*x3*x4>=a)
m.Equation(x1**2+x2**2+x3**2+x4**2==b)
m.Minimize(x1*x4*(x1+x2+x3)+x3)
m.options.SOLVER = 1 # APOPT solver

# Calculate obj at all meshgrid points
for i in range(amg.shape[0]):
    for j in range(bmg.shape[1]):
        a.MEAS = amg[i,j]
        b.MEAS = bmg[i,j]

        m.solve(disp=False)

        obj[i,j] = m.options.OBJFCNVAL
        print(amg[i,j],bmg[i,j],obj[i,j])

# plot 3D figure of results
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(amg, bmg, obj, \
       rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, \
       vmin = 10, vmax = 25, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_xlabel('a')
ax.set_ylabel('b')
ax.set_zlabel('obj')
plt.show()
```

Gekko also supports multi-threading as shown with the [same example with the threading package](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/ParallelComputing).

**Multi-Threaded Gekko Optimization**

```py
import numpy as np
import threading
import time, random
from gekko import GEKKO

class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, id, server, ai, bi):
        s = self
        s.id = id
        s.server = server
        s.m = GEKKO()
        s.a = ai
        s.b = bi
        s.objective = float('NaN')

        # initialize variables
        s.m.x1 = s.m.Var(1,lb=1,ub=5)
        s.m.x2 = s.m.Var(5,lb=1,ub=5)
        s.m.x3 = s.m.Var(5,lb=1,ub=5)
        s.m.x4 = s.m.Var(1,lb=1,ub=5)

        # Equations
        s.m.Equation(s.m.x1*s.m.x2*s.m.x3*s.m.x4>=s.a)
        s.m.Equation(s.m.x1**2+s.m.x2**2+s.m.x3**2+s.m.x4**2==s.b)

        # Objective
        s.m.Minimize(s.m.x1*s.m.x4*(s.m.x1+s.m.x2+s.m.x3)+s.m.x3)

        # Set global options
        s.m.options.IMODE = 3 # steady state optimization
        s.m.options.SOLVER = 1 # APOPT solver

        threading.Thread.__init__(s)

    def run(self):

        # Don't overload server by executing all scripts at once
        sleep_time = random.random()
        time.sleep(sleep_time)

        print('Running application ' + str(self.id) + '\n')

        # Solve
        self.m.solve(disp=False)

        # Results
        #print('')
        #print('Results')
        #print('x1: ' + str(self.m.x1.value))
        #print('x2: ' + str(self.m.x2.value))
        #print('x3: ' + str(self.m.x3.value))
        #print('x4: ' + str(self.m.x4.value))

        # Retrieve objective if successful
        if (self.m.options.APPSTATUS==1):
            self.objective = self.m.options.objfcnval
        else:
            self.objective = float('NaN')
        self.m.cleanup()

# Select server
server = 'https://byu.apmonitor.com'

# Optimize at mesh points
x = np.arange(20.0, 30.0, 2.0)
y = np.arange(30.0, 50.0, 2.0)
a, b = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Array of threads
threads = []

# Calculate objective at all meshgrid points

# Load applications
id = 0
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(b.shape[1]):
        # Create new thread
        threads.append(ThreadClass(id, server, a[i,j], b[i,j]))
        # Increment ID
        id += 1

# Run applications simultaneously as multiple threads
# Max number of threads to run at once
max_threads = 8
for t in threads:
    while (threading.activeCount()>max_threads):
        # check for additional threads every 0.01 sec
        time.sleep(0.01)
    # start the thread
    t.start()

# Check for completion
mt = 3.0 # max time
it = 0.0 # incrementing time
st = 1.0 # sleep time
while (threading.activeCount()>=1):
    time.sleep(st)
    it = it + st
    print('Active Threads: ' + str(threading.activeCount()))
    # Terminate after max time
    if (it>=mt):
        break

# Wait for all threads to complete
#for t in threads:
#    t.join()
#print('Threads complete')

# Initialize array for objective
obj = np.empty_like(a)

# Retrieve objective results
id = 0
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(b.shape[1]):
        obj[i,j] = threads[id].objective
        id += 1

# plot 3D figure of results
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(a, b, obj, \
                       rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, \
                       vmin = 12, vmax = 22, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_xlabel('a')
ax.set_ylabel('b')
ax.set_zlabel('obj')
ax.set_title('Multi-Threaded GEKKO')
plt.show()
```